# How can I structure this React Native screen to avoid the "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews" warning?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a screen with the following structure:

```
<ScrollView>
    <UserCard/>
    <DebtStatusCard/>
    <Header>
    <MaterialTabNavigator> <!-- screens have a FlatList component -->
<ScrollView>
```

How should I structure the ScrollView and FlatList in order to avoid the warning? I can't just stick everything above the MaterialTabNavigator into the header prop of the FlatList because the FlatList is rendered inside the views of the navigator and each view renders below it's tabs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please elaborate on what exactly you are trying to accomplish because I'm having a hard time understanding your question

Comment: @GiladShnoor I am doing a screen that has several components above a Material Tab Navigator (from React Nativation) component, then inside each view of the tab navigator I have a FlatList. Due to the height of the screen including all the components I need to wrap it inside a ScrollView. But I am getting a warning for it.